# Macro needed to replace the value in a column with custom data

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Basically, I have categories that are summed by a single letter of the alphabet when running the data, but obviously this wouldn't make sense to an outsider.

I need the macro to highlight in column that where this is a "G" it is replaced by "Custom name" and so on

"A" - changed to "Custom1"
"B" - changed to "Custom2" etc..

[image]

Comment: The issue I am having is that even though I want it to recognised a Y by itself and Replace with "Portables. When it goes to change cat P to "Custom" It will change the P in "Portables" as well

Comment: If your macro just runs through the column and changes each letter accordingly with a loop, it won't check the cells twice, and that problem should be gone. If you check every letter separately instead, like you would with search/ replace, then you get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a sheet or some columns to translate every letter to a "Custom name", and then refer to them that way.

But I will give you some examples on how to do it without having the names in any cells.

**Example 1**

Just loop all rows, and specify each letter and what it's name should change to.

```
Sub change()
Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, c As String
c = "E"
r = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To r
    Select Case UCase(Cells(i, c).Value)
        Case "A"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom1"
        Case "B"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom2"
        Case "C"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom3"
        Case "D"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom4"
        Case "E"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom5"
        Case "F"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom6"
        Case "G"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom7"
        Case "H"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom8"
        Case "I"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom9"
        Case "J"
            Cells(i, c).Value = "Custom10" 'And so on
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

For easy access the column name (number works as well) is specified by the variable `c`.
This will only work on exact matches, and ignore anything else.
It is not case sensitive (thanks to UCase), just remember to specify the letter in `case` as Upper case, or it won't work.

```
Case "A" 'Will work
Case "a" 'Won't work
```

This can turn into a pretty long list, so a different way of doing it is this:

**Example 2**

```
Sub changeArray()
Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, c As String

Dim Product
Product = Array("Custom1-A", "CustomB", "Custom3", "CustomD", , , , "Custom8", , , , , "Custom13", , , , , , , "Custom20", , , , , , "Custom25-Z")

c = "E"
r = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To r
    Select Case UCase(Cells(i, c).Value)
        Case "A" To "Z"
            Cells(i, c).Value = Product(Asc(UCase(Mid(Cells(i, c).Value, 1, 1))) - 65)
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```

The base of this code is the same. It still loops through the column specified by the variable `c`. But behaves quite differently.
This code picks up the first letter in the column, and if it's the letter a-z, it will change the cell to the custom name specified by the array.
It's not case sensitive, and will ignore anything but the first letter. So "A" and "Another1" will both be treated the same.

Comment: You're a genius, thanks man, the top one worked like a treat and will help going forward with much more. 

Thanks again